# How to handle picked images from gallery and camera in different devices?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have these codes to get an image from gallery or take photo with camera and after cropping it i want to show it in a bitmap `imageview`.

My problem is they work good in some devices and don't work in others!
please tell me which part of my code is making the problem ! Thank you

For example:
On LG G4 i not able to crop , but the photo from gallery and camera shows on image view
On Samsung Galaxy Alpha i can crop , image from camera shows good but i cant choose from gallery!

What should i do to work fine in all devices?

```
    private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // ******** code for crop image
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("cropped-rect", "true");

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     // Do nothing for now
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}



    private void captureWithCamera() {

    // call android default camera
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
    // ******** code for crop image
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("cropped-rect", "true");

    try {

        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Do nothing for now
    }
}
```

I think the problem must be in how i handle the returned data in onActivityResult method! Please take a look at my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            //Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions would be to put `uri` with `imageChooser`'s intent. Like this;

```
private void showCamera() {

    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DCIM");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File localFile2 = new File(file + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(localFile2);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            cameraIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri(null, Uri.fromFile(localFile2)));
        }

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    } catch (Exception localException) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityAddMemory.this, "Exception:" + localException, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

- On selecting from gallery, complete data is returned with intent. You can use `uri` by accessing `intent.getData()` or thumbnail `Bitmap` using `intent.getExtras().get("data")`. Don't use `imageUri` that you passed with that intent.
- On capturing from camera, in some devices intent is not null, but it's data is null. And in some devices, intent is null. Check both in `onActivityResult`.

  ```
  Uri uri;
  if (intent == null || intent.getData() == null) {
      uri = this.imageUri;
  } else {
      uri = intent.getData();
  }
  ```

Use this `uri` to display/upload your image.